# Angular HTTP Interceptor not hitting error functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, express

So I have pulled the interceptor straight from the angular HTTP documentation and yet this still doesn't work. The "request" and "response" functions get called ,but never the "requestError" or the "responseError".

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    return config; //gets called
                },

                'requestError': function (rejection) {
                    return $q.reject(rejection); //Never gets called
                },

                'response': function (response) {
                    return response; //gets called
                },

                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    return $q.reject(rejection); //Never gets called
                }
            };
        });
    }]);
```

On the server I am returning a 400, but really any error would do. And here is the service

```
User.publicProfileGetProfile = function (value, type) {
    return $http({
        url: '/public/profile/' + type + '/' + value,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    }, function(error){
        return error;
    });
};
```

No error functions are being called and every response goes through the response function. The standard angular error is displayed with the Bad Request (400) as usual. When the 400 error is returned, it is simply 'undefined' through the 'response' function in the interceptor.

Let me know if I've forgotten to include any important information.

Answer (score 0):

By using `return`, the error handler is **converting** the rejection to a success. Instead use `throw` to chain the rejection.

```
User.publicProfileGetProfile = function (value, type) {
    return $http({
        url: '/public/profile/' + type + '/' + value,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
        return response;
    }, function onReject(error){
        //return converts rejection to success
        //return error;

        //use throw to chain rejection
        throw error;
    });
};
```

Comment: So i've made that change... however the 'response' function (and is still undefined) still gets called and in the controller, the error result still never gets called.

Comment: The `errorResponse` interceptor gets called for status 400 responses in [this JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hawfLnx1/).

Comment: Thank you! When I saw that the JSFiddle was working properly, I made sure mine looked exactly the same. When it didn't work, I looked around to see if I had any other interceptors that might cause problems. I had another interceptor that was being hit first and returning any errors as responses, then they would go through this one and it would process it as a successful response. I removed it and everything seems to be working correct now!

Comment: So your other interceptor was **converting** the rejection to a success. Be aware that an error interceptor without a return will **convert** the rejection to a success with a `null` value. To chain a rejection, one must either `throw error;` or `return $q.reject(error);`.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw that the JSFiddle (from @georgeawg) was working properly, I made sure mine looked exactly the same. When it didn't work, I looked around to see if I had any other interceptors that might cause problems. I had another interceptor that was being hit first and returning any errors as responses, then they would go through this one and it would process it as a successful response. I removed it and everything seems to be working correct now!